# Hide/Display Form Section

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a table in which five fields have upload rows.Each time, I submit a row,the pages refreshes. However, I want to hide all the 4 rows, when the first submit button is clicked, then it should show the next row, and hide the previous row. This should continue till the last one. I have tried the following, but not working. ie all the rows are displaying. I need assitance on how to achieve this feat.

```
<script>
$("#othBtn1").click(function(){
 $("#oth2").show();
$("#oth1").hide();
$("#oth3").hide();
$("#oth4").hide();
$("#oth5").hide();
});
$("#othBtn2").click(function(){
 $("#oth3").show();
$("#oth1").hide();
$("#oth2").hide();
$("#oth4").hide();
$("#oth5").hide();
});
</script>
```

This will continue till the last button. See the HTML below:

```
<table width="96%" border="0" style="margin-top:10px;" align="left" id="tableRec"class="table table-bordered">
   <tr id="oth1">
    <th width="26%">Other Request (1):<small>  &nbsp;(Attachment Required) <i> Attach each other request per line</i></small></th>
    <td width="33%">Description:<input type="text" name="tdesc1" value="" placeholder="Enter the Description" class="form-control"></td><td width="12%">Amount:<input type="text" name="tamt1" value="" placeholder="Enter Amount and click Add to Request Button" class="form-control" /></td>
    <td>File(1):<input type="file" name="jfile1"/></td>
    <td width="29%"><input type="submit" name="othBtn1"  id="othBtn1" value="Add to Request" class="btn btn-success"  /> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="oth2">
    <th width="26%">Other Request (2):<small>  &nbsp;(Attachment Required) <i> Attach each other request per line</i></small></th>
    <td width="33%">Description:<input type="text" name="tdesc2" value="" placeholder="Enter the Description" class="form-control"></td><td width="12%">Amount:<input type="text" name="tamt2" value="" placeholder="Enter Amount and click Add to Request Button" class="form-control" /></td>
    <td>File(2):<input type="file" name="jfile2"/></td>
    <td width="29%"><input type="submit" name="othBtn2" id="othBtn2" value="Add to Request" class="btn btn-success" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="oth3">
    <th width="26%">Other Request (3):<small>  &nbsp;(Attachment Required) <i> Attach each other request per line</i></small></th>
    <td width="33%">Description:<input type="text" name="tdesc3" value="" placeholder="Enter the Description" class="form-control"></td><td width="12%">Amount:<input type="text" name="tamt3" value="" placeholder="Enter Amount and click Add to Request Button" class="form-control" /></td>
    <td>File(3):<input type="file" name="jfile3"/></td>
    <td width="29%"><input type="submit" name="othBtn3" id="othBtn3" value="Add to Request" class="btn btn-success" /> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="oth4">
    <th width="26%">Other Request (4):<small>  &nbsp;(Attachment Required) <i> Attach each other request per line</i></small></th>
    <td width="33%">Description:<input type="text" name="tdesc4" value="" placeholder="Enter the Description" class="form-control"></td><td width="12%">Amount:<input type="text" name="tamt4" value="" placeholder="Enter Amount and click Add to Request Button" class="form-control" /></td>
    <td>File(4):<input type="file" name="jfile4"/></td>
    <td width="29%"><input type="submit" name="othBtn4"  id="othBtn4"value="Add to Request" class="btn btn-success" /> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="oth5">
    <th width="26%">Other Request (5):<small>  &nbsp;(Attachment Required) <i> Attach each other request per line</i></small></th>
    <td width="33%">Description:<input type="text" name="tdesc5" value="" placeholder="Enter the Description" class="form-control"></td><td width="12%">Amount:<input type="text" name="tamt5" value="" placeholder="Enter Amount and click Add to Request Button" class="form-control" /></td>
    <td>File(5):<input type="file" name="jfile5"/></td>
    <td width="29%"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: You are missing a `<` at the start of the table.

Comment: you are missing `#` in every `hide()` as `$("oth1").hide();`

Comment: @Poonam: it was an omission. So, what can i do?

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of issues.

1. You are missing a opening bracket for your table `<`.
2. You are missing the `#` in your selector.

Change,

```
table width="96%" border="0" style="margin-top:10px;" align="left" id="tableRec"class="table table-bordered">
```

to,

```
<table width="96%" border="0" style="margin-top:10px;" align="left" id="tableRec"class="table table-bordered">
```

**and** change,

```
$("#othBtn1").click(function() {
    $("#oth2").show();
    $("oth1").hide();
    $("oth3").hide();
    $("oth4").hide();
    $("oth5").hide();
});
$("#othBtn2").click(function() {
    $("#oth3").show();
    $("oth1").hide();
    $("oth2").hide();
    $("oth4").hide();
    $("oth5").hide();
});
```

to,

```
$("#othBtn1").click(function() {
    $("#oth2").show();
    $("#oth1").hide();
    $("#oth3").hide();
    $("#oth4").hide();
    $("#oth5").hide();
});

$("#othBtn2").click(function() {
    $("#oth3").show();
    $("#oth1").hide();
    $("#oth2").hide();
    $("#oth4").hide();
    $("#oth5").hide();
});
```

Comment: I have tried it, still not working. ALl the nutton are showing after the click. It also all show on document.load as well.

Answer (score 0):

In your example you missed the `#` in front of the `id` selectors.

And you can simple combine everything to a single event listener. No need for doing it manually for each button.

```js
$("#tableRec input[id^=othBtn]").click(function() {
    $("#tableRec tr").hide();
    $(this).closest("tr").next().show();
});
```

```css
tr {
  display: none;
}

tr:first-child {
  display: table-row;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="tableRec">
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td><input type="submit" id="othBtn1" value="Add to Request" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td><input type="submit" id="othBtn2" value="Add to Request" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td><input type="submit" id="othBtn3" value="Add to Request" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>4</td>
    <td><input type="submit" id="othBtn4" value="Add to Request" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>table end</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: How  will i reference the Id I want to do and hide?

Comment: In your example you always show the next `tr`, true? Than you don't need any reference. Just use `.next()`. My example should work for you as it is. @Dave

Comment: Yes, i always show the next tr. what will be in the ^ of your code? I have tried the example, still did not work. Upon clicking the first button, all the other 4 still show? but i want it to be shown one after the other upon click.

Comment: The `^` select all element, where the `id` starts with `othBtn`. I've created a working example for you above, showing that it works. @Dave

Comment: I tried this, and the snippet works correctly on this page as shown above, however, i really cannot fathom, while it's not running on my system. I added <script></script> and <style></style> to the first and second paragraph above before the table. Is that the issue?